# How to add fe_group in Controller

Tags: typo3, extbase

I want to set the "standard" TYPO3 field "fe_group" in the extbase controller. As far I see there no "standard" getters and setters? https://typo3.org/api/typo3cms/class_t_y_p_o3_1_1_c_m_s_1_1_extbase_1_1_domain_object_1_1_abstract_entity.html

I tried to implement them in the model, but it does not work - I do not get any error but it is never set.

What exactly I want to do:
I have an object of type \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Domain\Model\FrontendUserGroup and I have an object of my record type (I can set other fields without any problems).

Now I want to do something like:

```
$myobject->addFe_group($feusergroup);
```

Do I have to implement this by my own to my model? I tried to implement fe_group as ObjectStorage and also as string - does not work? :-(

Does anyone have a solution for this?

Thank you

Christian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all: In models please name functions and properties lowerCamelCase. So a field "fe_group" in TCA would become "feGroup" in the model and the function would be "addFeGroup".

FrontendUserGroup model has a function addSubgroup to add other groups as subobjects. Is this the right thing for your purpose or what you need those relation to another group for?
https://typo3.org/api/typo3cms/class_t_y_p_o3_1_1_c_m_s_1_1_extbase_1_1_domain_1_1_model_1_1_frontend_user_group.html

Comment: Thank you @Paul Beck. You are right: the field "fe_group" in TCA has to become "feGroup" in the model. 

` /**
     * feGroup
     *
     * @var \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\ObjectStorage<\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Domain\Model\FrontendUserGroup>
     */
    protected $feGroup = null;`

Same for the name of the functions, e.g. addFeGroup or getFeGroup.